# spring get messagesource in java based configuration

Tags: java, spring, jsp

I want to get messages loaded by messageSource bean, and want to use them in application context (java-based @Configuration class).

But I do not know how to.

I worked like below:

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages={
"com.musicovery12.study.service",
"com.musicovery12.study.dao"
})
public class ApplicationContext {

@Bean
public MessageSource messageSource(){
    ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource messageSource = new ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource();
    messageSource.setBasename("classpath:META-INF/application.properties");
    messageSource.setUseCodeAsDefaultMessage(true);
    messageSource.setDefaultEncoding("UTF-8");
    return messageSource;
}

@Bean
public DataSource dataSource(){
    BasicDataSource dataSource = new BasicDataSource();
    dataSource.setDriverClassName(/*${db.driver-name}*/); // I want to set the parameter as given message stored by messageSource

    return dataSource;
}
```

}

Any suggestion?

Thanks.

Comment: Why are you using a `MessageSource` to load properties? You are using the wrong tool...

Comment: Yes, I was wrong. So I changed to property placeholder. Thanks to point me out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@Bean
public DataSource dataSource(){
    String driverClassName = messageSource().getMessage(...);
    BasicDataSource dataSource = new BasicDataSource();
    dataSource.setDriverClassName(driverClassName); // I want to set the parameter as given message stored by messageSource

    return dataSource;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for reply. But, is it that ReoladableResourceBundleMessageSource is created every time when calling "messageSource()" in dataSource()? I want to have messageSource as singleton.

Comment: Is your `dataSource()` and `messageSource()` Singleton? I say yes because this is the default behavior. As Spring states: `@Bean is a method-level annotation and a direct analog of the XML <bean/> element. The annotation supports most of the attributes offered by <bean/>, such as: init-method, destroy-method, autowiring, lazy-init, dependency-check, depends-on and scope. ` `The DefaultScopes class provides string constants for each of these four scopes. SINGLETON is the default, and can be overridden by supplying the scope attribute to @Bean annotation: `

Comment: so do you mean any method with @Bean(Singleton) returns singleton object on every call?  Thank you. I may have to find the spring doc..

Comment: https://docs.spring.io/spring-javaconfig/docs/1.0.0.M4/reference/html/ch02s02.html